# Linq and DataContext

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext

Would it be ok to have only one DataContext per app and share that through an singleton?

I ask this because i would like to have the DataContext in every form but i realized that, if i change some enity in one DataContext, i have ro refresh it, if used before.

eg form1:

```
db = GetContext()
item=(from p in db.Table where p.id=1 select p)
```

on another form

```
db = GetContext()
item=(from p in db.Table where p.id=1 select p)
item.value="test"
```

back on the original form i have to do

```
db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, item)
```

even if i do a new

```
item=(from p in db.Table where p.id=1 select p)
```

(without the refresh) the value will not be updated

Is DataContext threadsafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not okay* when using `DataContext` as singleton, `DataContext` is implemented using *Unit of Work pattern* with internal cache inside, purpose of internal cache is to avoid the round trips to database and for changes tracking. Keeping `DataContext` as singleton would make internal cache increasing then lead to memory-leak for the time being.

The *best practice* is the lifetime of DataContext should be per thread, most of IoC containers support this, just choose one and use.

`DataContext` is not thread-safe, so presumably you implemented thead-safe singleton using static constructor or `Lazy<>`

Answer (score 4):

> Would it be ok to have only one DataContext per app and share that through an singleton?

Well, that's certainly not what it's *designed* for - and if you had multiple threads performing multiple operations, it *certainly* wouldn't be a good idea.

Just like database connections, it's best to create the context when you need it, do whatever you need to do, then create a new one when you've got a new set of operations to perform.